# TypeScript Declarations Conflict

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, vuejs3, vue-cli

Repro: https://github.com/wenfangdu/d-ts-conflict-repro

`shims-vue.d.ts`

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
/* eslint-enable */

import 'vue'

declare module 'vue' {
  interface HTMLAttributes extends interface {
    vModel?: unknown
  }
}
```

Run `npm run serve`, after the dev server starts up, these errors are printed:

```js
ERROR in src/main.ts:2:17
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './App.vue'. 'D:/Repos/d-ts-conflict-repro/src/App.vue.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    1 | import { createApp } from 'vue'
  > 2 | import App from './App.vue'
      |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import router from './router'
    4 | import store from './store'
    5 |

ERROR in src/router/index.ts:17:46
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../views/About.vue'. 'D:/Repos/d-ts-conflict-repro/src/views/About.vue.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    15 |     // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    16 |     component: () =>
  > 17 |       import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue'),
       |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    18 |   },
    19 | ]
    20 |
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: why did you add that second declaration?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I wanted to use `vModel` on `<input />`.

Comment: vue directives work fine as html attributes

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'm using TSX, `v-model` is allowed, but `vModel` isn't, so I had to add this. If I put it in another `.d.ts`, everything works fine, but it throws when they are in the same `.d.ts`, I don't understand why.

Comment: but why do you want to use `vModel` instead of `v-model`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Sorry for being rude, I understand your point now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `declare module '*.vue'` should be in a global scope. i.e. a top-level declaration in a non-module (where a module is a file with at least one top-level `import` or `export`).

A declaration of the form `declare module 'vue'` in a module is an augmentation. For more details see [Typescript Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

These two groups of declarations should live in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do following:

```typescript
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
/* eslint-enable */
import * as vue from 'vue';
declare module 'vue' {
  interface HTMLAttributes {
    vModel?: number;
  }
}
```

However, this will show only in `TypeScript` code, not in the Vue markup. Reason is that markup get's its' intellisense from Vue plugin, not from TypeScript language service.

Comment: `vModel` doesn't show up in `<input />` attribute IntelliSense though.

Comment: I fixed the answer, but you wont' get `vModel` in HTML markup. In addition, by default HTML markup should not be case sensitive, so `v-model` is correct convention to use there.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried out in my project and it works as follows :

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>

  export interface HTMLAttributes {
    vModel?: any;
  }
  export default component
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! However, `vModel` doesn't show up in `<input />` IntelliSense, have you tried it in `.tsx` file?

Comment: Try to rerun npm run serve, i tried it with tsx extension